# DSI Display not detected on reboot

Tags: pi-4, display

Setup: Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB) running Raspberry Pi OS. 5" DSI Display and 7" HDMI Display.

From a cold-boot, the DSI display is automatically detected and works as expected.

During a reboot, only HDMI is detected. Xrandr does not display the DSI output and ignores commands to initialize it.

Why is Xrandr not detecting my DSI output after a reboot? Is config.txt being ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Even it is an older post, here are my 50 cents !

- DSI display should be powered prior to OS start detection
- At cold boot, RPi 4 does that but upon reboot, USB power starts late, therefore no display detected.
- To overcome this, add

```
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
```

in /boot/config.txt to prevent USB power cycle at reboot.
Or use a 5V pigtail cable to supply power towards display not involving USB.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior on a Raspberry Pi 3 and ended up turning off the vc4 driver to get things to work consistently as per this question (I am using the official Raspberry Pi 7" display):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256142/cant-rotate-default-screen-on-raspberry-pi3-running-manjaro-with-x11